# How to receive large XML files in REST web services

Tags: java, web-services, rest, memory, load

How do I re-design a high-load REST web service?

I have an existing Java-based REST web service that's receiving a XML file as a String. There are several clients that are sending XML files to this service. It turns out that large XML files (>100 MB) that being sent to this service as Strings, cause causing the web service to slow down, freeze and crash (OutOfMemory).

How can I modify the web service to receive and handle large XML data, without affecting the existing clients?

This is what the existing web service signature is:

```
@POST
@Path("/acceptMessage")
public String acceptMessage(String request) throws Exception;
```

The "String request" is causing the load/performance problems. Any changes that I make to the web service signature cannot affect the existing web service clients.

What are my options?

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: Apache CXF with Spring Web Services, running on Tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Change the `String request` parameter to `Reader request`.  According to section 4.2.4 of the JAX-RS specification, it could also be `File request`.  And there are a number of other valid types which you may or may not find useful:

- `javax.activation.DataSource` All media types (*/*).
- `javax.xml.transform.Source` XML types (text/xml, application/xml and application/*+xml).
- `javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement` and application-supplied JAXB classes XML media types (text/xml, application/xml and application/*+xml).

Comment: The Reader is a good option, and an ideal solution to begin with. Of course, now my downstream POJO services that also used Strings, need to be changed.